# Sequelize join two columns of one table to the same column of another table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table **Relation** with columns *userId1* and *userId2* it basically stores the relation between two users, *userId1* and *userId2* is foreign key here referenced from the **User** tables id (PK) column.

```
   id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    userId1: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    userId2: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM,
    },
```

Then there is another table **Posts** containing information about posts.

```
          id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
          },
          content: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: false,
          },
          postedBy: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
                allowNull: false,
          },
```

I want to get lists of post of only those user who have a relation with me like *friends*, means my id lets suppose is **1** and it is in *userId1* column and userId2 column has **id** in it, then I want to fetch all posts of value **2** from **posts** *postedBy* column.
This case can be vice versa as my id can be in *userId2* column and I need to get all posts of the user whose value is in *userId1* column.

I have read through all the questions and answers like multiple associations but it is just not working for me.

This is my associations in **Posts** model

```
      Posts.hasOne(RelationModel, {
        foreignKey: 'userId1',
        sourceKey: 'postedBy',
        as: 'first',
      })

       Posts.hasOne(RelationModel, {
            foreignKey: 'userId2',
            sourceKey: 'postedBy',
            as: 'second',
        })
```

Below is my include array.

```
          include:[
                   {
                    model: RelationModel,
                    as: 'first',
                    where: {
                        status: 'accepted',
                        [Op.or]: [
                            { userId1: request.user.id },
                            { userId2: request.user.id },
                        ],
                    },
                },
                {
                    model: RelationModel,
                    as: 'second',
                    where: {
                        status: 'accepted',
                        [Op.or]: [
                            { userId1: request.user.id },
                            { userId2: request.user.id },
                        ],
                    },
                }
               ]
```

The query being generated from this is below, where **151** is the logged in user id, means my id

```
SELECT 
    `posts`.*,
    `first`.*,
    `second`.*
FROM
    `posts` AS `posts`
        INNER JOIN
    `relations` AS `first` ON `posts`.`postedBy` = `first`.`userId1`
        AND (`first`.`userId1` = 151
        OR `first`.`userId2` = 151)
        AND `first`.`status` = 'accepted'
        INNER JOIN
    `relations` AS `second` ON `posts`.`postedBy` = `second`.`userId2`
        AND (`second`.`userId1` = 151
        OR `second`.`userId2` = 151)
        AND `second`.`status` = 'accepted'
WHERE
    `posts`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC , `posts`.`id` ASC;
```

But the query I want to build is below

```
SELECT 
    `posts`.*,
    `first`.*
FROM
    `posts` AS `posts`
        INNER JOIN
    `relations` AS `first` ON (`posts`.`postedBy` = `first`.`userId2`
        OR `posts`.`postedBy` = `first`.`userId1`)
        AND (`first`.`userId1` = 151
        OR `first`.`userId2` = 151)
        AND `first`.`isFriend` = TRUE
        AND `first`.`status` = 'accepted'
WHERE
    `posts`.`deletedAt` IS NULL
ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC , `posts`.`id` ASC;
```

How to construct this query in sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a unique `as` keyword for each relationship in the association as well as on the `include` for your query.

```js
Posts.hasOne(RelationModel, {
  foreignKey: 'userId1',
  sourceKey: 'postedBy',
  as: 'first',
});

Posts.hasOne(RelationModel, {
  foreignKey: 'userId2',
  sourceKey: 'postedBy',
  as: 'second',
});
```

Then when you query you specify the unique `as` that identifies the relationship for the join

```
Post.findByPk(id, {
  include: [{
    model: RelationModel,
    as: 'first',
  },
  {
    model: RelationModel,
    as: 'second',
  }],
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already did that but forgot to add it in question, I have updated my question please have a look.